# Múltiples condicionales en Pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas

soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación.

Tengo un pequeño proyecto, donde hago una consulta a la base de datos:

cursor.execute("Select fecha, monto1, monto2, monto3, producto from productos)

Hago lo siguiente para obtener tanto campos como resultados:

```
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
results = []
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    results.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))

Data = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

Luego quisiera realizar una condicional, lo intenté así:

```
Data.loc[(Data['producto'=='limpieza']) & (Data['monto1']>0),"monto2"] = 0
```

Con esto lo que quiero hacer es colocarle 0 a la columna monto2 cuando el producto sea "limpieza" y el monto1 sea mayor a 0.

Me da el siguiente error:

> ```
> raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: False
> ```

Comment: Hola, tienes un error tipográfico en `(Data['producto'=='limpieza']`), debe ser **`(Data['producto'] == 'limpieza')`**. El corchete de cierre que marca el indexado lo tienes mal posicionado, en vez de usar `'producto'` como indice, le indicas que use `'producto'=='limpieza`,  lo que se traduce en `Data[False]`, dado que la expresión de comparación `'producto'=='limpieza'` es falsa, por eso te dice `KeyError: False`.